# Crosstabs with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table, crosstab

I love the data.table package in R, and I think it could help me perform sophisticated cross tabulation tasks, but haven't figured out how to use the package to do tasks similar to `table`.

Here's some replication survey data:

```
opinion <- c("gov", "market", "gov", "gov")
ID <- c("resp1", "resp2", "resp3", "resp4")
party <- c("GOP", "GOP", "democrat", "GOP")

df <- data.frame(ID, opinion, party)
```

In tables, counting the number of opinions by party is as simple as `table(df$opinion, df$party).`

I've managed to do something similar in data.table, but the result is clunky and it adds a separate column.

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, .N, by="party"]
```

There's a number of grouping operations in data.table that could be great for fast and sophisticated crosstabs of survey data, but i haven't found any tutorials on how to it. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` (See the *Efficient reshaping using data.tables* vignette on the [project wiki](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) or on the [CRAN project page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html)).

```
dcast(dt, opinion~party, value.var='ID', length)
```

#### Benchmarks

If we use a slightly bigger dataset and compare the speed using `dcast` from `reshape2` and `data.table`

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(ID=1:1e6, opinion=sample(letters, 1e6, replace=TRUE),
  party= sample(1:9, 1e6, replace=TRUE))
system.time(dcast(df, opinion ~ party, value.var='ID', length))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.278   0.013   0.293 
system.time(dcast(setDT(df), opinion ~ party, value.var='ID', length))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 0.022   0.000   0.023 

system.time(setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(opinion, party)])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.018   0.001   0.018
```

The third option is slightly better but it is in 'long' format.  If the OP wants to have a 'wide' format, the `data.table` `dcast` can be used.

NOTE: I am using the the devel version i.e. `v1.9.7`, but the CRAN should be fast enough.

Comment: this works, but it basically nullifies the the data.table package itself. most of the benefits from data.table from from the subsetting and grouping operations, like "by." This essentially treats the dt as a data.frame. Am i missing something, or is the data.table package just not good for survey data?

Comment: @tom No, it is not treating it as `data.frame`.  The `dcast` is from the `data.table` package and not from the `reshape2` and is optimized for speed.

Comment: @tom Updated with benchmarks.

Comment: @akrun are you using 1.9.7? I'm wondering if you're getting the boost from the solution to [FR #1251](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1251) (which, if I understand, isn't in current CRAN release, 1.9.6); if so this should be mentioned. I remember `dt[,table(x,y)]` being competitive with `dt[,.N,by=.(x,y)]` but that's no longer the case with the update.

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Yes, I am using 1.9.7.  But, the CRAN version should stilll be faster than reshape2 dcast.

Comment: @akrun I believe so, but `dt[,table(x,y)]` is another straightforward option (faster than `reshape2::dcast` on my machine but slower than `data.table::dcast`)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Would that be memory efficient?

Comment: That I'm not sure. I do use `table` when speed isn't priority 1 because it's so much more readable. But the `.N` approach is better suited to generating 3- or n-way tables and, as you demonstrated, much faster.